# Google charts api removes part of string when creating qr code in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We want to create a qr code in google sheets that opens a form with filled in values.
This is the url we want to create:

```
"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeSsFWHuQt1qdeymL3IUHftT3dh54FNTmG6NrDhcBrqFBIoZQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1299510889=Grosemans+Kurt+-+4&entry.619773178=A&entry.1305845422=2"
```

We make the qr code with following formula:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="&CELLREFERENCE)
```

However the charts api removes the parameters from the string and only redericts to the form without the filled in parameters.
(this is removed from the string: **&entry.1299510889=Grosemans+Kurt+-+4&entry.619773178=A&entry.1305845422=2**)

How can we solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML data not pulling out in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186642/html-data-not-pulling-out-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By concatenating the URL as you are currently doing, the resulting URL looks like the following:

`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeSsFWHuQt1qdeymL3IUHftT3dh54FNTmG6NrDhcBrqFBIoZQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1299510889=Grosemans+Kurt+-+4&entry.619773178=A&entry.1305845422=2`

This may not seem wrong at first, but the issue is that the query parameters of the QR code's URL are understood as part of the top-level URL. i.e.

Base URL: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart`

Query strings:

- `cht=qr`
- `chl=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeSsFWHuQt1qdeymL3IUHftT3dh54FNTmG6NrDhcBrqFBIoZQ/viewform`
- `usp=pp_url`
- `entry.1299510889=Grosemans+Kurt+-+4`
- `entry.619773178=A`
- `entry.1305845422=2`

In order to obtain the the result you are looking for, you must use the **ENCODEURL** function as following:

`=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="&ENCODEURL(CELLREFERENCE))`

This will result in:

Base URL: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart`

Query strings:

- `cht=qr`
- `chl=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeSsFWHuQt1qdeymL3IUHftT3dh54FNTmG6NrDhcBrqFBIoZQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1299510889=Grosemans+Kurt+-+4&entry.619773178=A&entry.1305845422=2`

I hope this is useful to you. Regards.